# How to pass down function with "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, this

I have function, which is setting value for `hitCounter`.
Could you tell me, how to pass it down to another function, so it still works?

```
this.view.hitCounter.value(someValue);     // This function works here.

function DoSomething() {
   this.view.hitCounter.value(someValue);   // I want it to work here.
};
```

I don't have full code and don't know the scope. It is script inside visualisation creation tool.

Comment: `DoSomething` has its _own_ `this`. Make it an arrow function, or alias the outer `this` so it's still accessible.

Comment: Do you have a chance sending parameter to `DoSomething` method? If yes, send `this` as parameter with named e.g. `oThis`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, arrow function do the job, thank You. But, could you tell me how should it look if I'd like to have it with `function`?

Comment: Various options are covered on the duplicate.